# File durability settings

Tags: c++, windows, file

I'm working on a ACID database software product and I have some questions about file durability on WinOS.

[CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has two attributes, **FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH** and **FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING** - do I need both these to achieve file durability (ie. override all kinds of disk or OS file caching)? I'm asking since they seem to do the same thing, and setting **FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING** causes [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to throw an **ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER** error.

Comment: The error you're receiving when using FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING is because your memory address of your buffer your using (for read or write) is not properly aligned. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950(v=vs.85).aspx) for information on why this is the case, along with benefits, and potential pitfalls, of foregoing the buffered IO system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` specifies no caching at al. No read nor write cache all data goes directly to and from your application to disk. This is mostly usefull if you read such large chunks that caching is useless or you do your own caching. *Note WhozCraig's comment on properly aligning your data when using this flag.*

`FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` only means that writes should written directly to disk before the function returns. This is enough to achieve ACID while it still gives the option to the OS to cache data from the file.

Using `FlushFileBuffers()` can provide a more efficient approach for achieving ACID as you can do several writes to a file and then flush them in one go. Combining writes in one flush is very important as non cached writes will limit you to the spindle speed of your harddrive. 120 non cached writes or flushes per second max for a 7200 rpm disk.

Comment: your description of FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING is not completely accurate. It *does* tell the IO system to not setup buffers for reads or writes. However, the key data you;'re missing is the alignment requirements of any buffer **you** provide during a `ReadFile` or `WriteFile` call. The buffer you provide **must** be on a memory addressed aligned to an even multiple of the sector size of the volume the file exists on. For more information on this see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: We have our own buffer manager that handles disk sector to internal memory caching, would you still recommend FILE_FLA_WRITE_THROUGH over FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING? Are there performance differences between the two? When it comes to FlushFileBuffers I don't think we should do that as we need to flush individual disk sectors - our disk manager handles all multithreaded file access logic including proper disk sector flushing.

Comment: Hard to say. The overhead of OS buffering is slight so I doubt you will gain much by switching it off and you might gain something in certain cases by leaving it on... Best to test it I think.